# Commutator of Noether charge and four-momentum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, field-theory, noethers-theorem

Given Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi$, I have to prove $[Q,P^\mu]=-iP^\mu$ without using creation-annihilation operators. Here $Q$ is Noether charge for the symmetry $\phi'(x)=e^\lambda \phi(e^\lambda x)$ and $P^\mu=\int \Pi. \partial^\mu\phi .d^3x$ is the four-momentum.

My $Q$ is turning out to be $\int d^3x (1+x^\mu \partial _\mu )\phi(x)\Pi(x)$ where $\Pi(x)$ is canonical momentum (correct me if I'm wrong). But I'm stuck at a step of the calculation where I have to compute $[Q,P^\mu]=\int \int d^3x' (1+x^{\nu'} \partial _{\nu'} )\phi(x')[\Pi(x'),\Pi(x) \partial^\mu \phi]d^3x$

Comment: Your last line does not look right. How did you find it? You need to compute just two nonvanishing commutators.

Comment: If the As commute between themselves, and so do the Bs,   you surely understand the identity [A1 B1, A2 B2]=A1 [B1,A2] B2 + A2 [A1,B2] B1 ?

Comment: You could edit your question to completion.